# WebCrawler stop method logic [Concurrency in practice 7.2.5]

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, cancellation

I have read 7.2.5 chapter from concurrency in practice(Limitations of shutdownNow)

Issue of shutdownNow that it returns only not started tasks.

At first we create ExecutorService that keeps track of cancelled tasks after shutdown.

**TrackingExecutor:**

```
/**
 * TrackingExecutor
 * <p/>
 * ExecutorService that keeps track of cancelled tasks after shutdown
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
public class TrackingExecutor extends AbstractExecutorService {
    private final ExecutorService exec;
    private final Set<Runnable> tasksCancelledAtShutdown =
            Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Runnable>());

    public TrackingExecutor(ExecutorService exec) {
        this.exec = exec;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        exec.shutdown();
    }

    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        return exec.shutdownNow();
    }

    public boolean isShutdown() {
        return exec.isShutdown();
    }

    public boolean isTerminated() {
        return exec.isTerminated();
    }

    public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException {
        return exec.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
    }

    public List<Runnable> getCancelledTasks() {
        if (!exec.isTerminated())
            throw new IllegalStateException(/*...*/);
        return new ArrayList<Runnable>(tasksCancelledAtShutdown);
    }

    public void execute(final Runnable runnable) {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {
                    if (isShutdown()
                            && Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                        tasksCancelledAtShutdown.add(runnable);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then we create Crawler which uses `TrackingExecutor`:

**crawler:**

```
/**
 * WebCrawler
 * <p/>
 * Using TrackingExecutorService to save unfinished tasks for later execution
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
public abstract class WebCrawler {
    private volatile TrackingExecutor exec;
    @GuardedBy("this") private final Set<URL> urlsToCrawl = new HashSet<URL>();

    private final ConcurrentMap<URL, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<URL, Boolean>();
    private static final long TIMEOUT = 500;
    private static final TimeUnit UNIT = MILLISECONDS;

    public WebCrawler(URL startUrl) {
        urlsToCrawl.add(startUrl);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        exec = new TrackingExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        for (URL url : urlsToCrawl) submitCrawlTask(url);
        urlsToCrawl.clear();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            saveUncrawled(exec.shutdownNow());
            if (exec.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, UNIT))
                saveUncrawled(exec.getCancelledTasks());
        } finally {
            exec = null;
        }
    }

    protected abstract List<URL> processPage(URL url);

    private void saveUncrawled(List<Runnable> uncrawled) {
        for (Runnable task : uncrawled)
            urlsToCrawl.add(((CrawlTask) task).getPage());
    }

    private void submitCrawlTask(URL u) {
        exec.execute(new CrawlTask(u));
    }

    private class CrawlTask implements Runnable {
        private final URL url;

        CrawlTask(URL url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        private int count = 1;

        boolean alreadyCrawled() {
            return seen.putIfAbsent(url, true) != null;
        }

        void markUncrawled() {
            seen.remove(url);
            System.out.printf("marking %s uncrawled%n", url);
        }

        public void run() {
            for (URL link : processPage(url)) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                    return;
                submitCrawlTask(link);
            }
        }

        public URL getPage() {
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

lets research  `stop` method:

```
 public synchronized void stop() throws InterruptedException {
     try {
         saveUncrawled(exec.shutdownNow()); //1
         if (exec.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, UNIT)) //2
             saveUncrawled(exec.getCancelledTasks()); //3
         } finally {
             exec = null;
         }
     }
 }
```

---

```
saveUncrawled(exec.shutdownNow()); //1
```

In row `1` we do `shutdownNow` and save returned(not started) tasks.
If I understand correct `shutdownNow` returns not started tasks and interrupt already started tasks

```
exec.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, UNIT) //2
```

Additionally we want to add cancelled tasks to this collection.
At line `2` we give time and await termination  with timeout.

**Question №1**

*Why Do we give timeOut for this operation?*

As I understand - `shutdownNow` interrupts in progress tasks anyway. And I don't see reason to wait.

```
exec.getCancelledTasks()
```

`awaitTermination` method returns `true` in case if task were completed successfully thus it is unclear for me why we try to add cancelled tasks at this case.

Please, clarify logic of `stop` method.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the timeout for `boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`:

Interrupting a thread does not necessarily stop it immediately (or at all). To quote the [Java Tutorial on Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html):

> An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else. It's up to the programmer to decide exactly how a thread responds to an interrupt, but it is very common for the thread to terminate. This is the usage emphasized in this lesson.

It's also directly spelled out in the javadoc for [`ExecutorService#shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--):

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

Other reasons why a Thread may still be alive after interruption are mentioned in the javadoc of [`Thread#interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--). For example:

> Unless the current thread is interrupting itself, which is always permitted, the `checkAccess` method of this thread is invoked, which may cause a `SecurityException` to be thrown.

The logic of the `stop()` method is not obvious without carefully studying the javadoc of [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (see section "Usage Examples", 2nd example). The problem of `shutdownNow()` is that it tries to cancel all threads but (a) this might take some time and (b) there's no guarantee that it succeeds (see above). `awaitTermination(long, TimeUnit)` allows to track this progress. I'll go line by line through the `stop()` method:

```
saveUncrawled(exec.shutdownNow());
```

Shutdown of the `ExecutorService` is initiated and tasks that were awaiting execution are collected. Completed tasks are ignored and tasks currently being executed are ignored, too.

```
if (exec.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, UNIT))
```

`shutdownNow()` just signals the currently running tasks that they should stop via interruption. It does not kill them. Also, stopping work after being interrupted takes time. Hence you have to wait for the execution to complete. The timeout is there to prevent you from blocking forever in case some tasks never complete (for whatever reason). Keep in mind that threads can ignore interruption or it might take them longer than the remaining timeout to stop their work. Therefore there might still be some tasks left after `awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, UNIT)`. The `TrackingExecutor` collects only tasks that could be cancelled. But not the ones that might still be executing after the timeout expires.

```
saveUncrawled(exec.getCancelledTasks());
```

If all tasks could be cancelled, `awaitTermination()` returns `true`. In this case all cancelled tasks are collected. If not all tasks could be cancelled (i.e. `awaitTermination()` returns `false`) there would still be some tasks left that are not handled.

Comment: If task was in progress and at this moment was interrupted, it counts as cancellable. Why should we wait its termination, especially in wrong ifclause

Comment: I've amended the explanation of the `stop()` method.

Comment: in case **exec.awaitTermination** returns true we try to add additional tasks to the collection

Comment: `saveUncrawled(exec.shutdownNow())` gives you only the tasks that haven't been started yet, not the ones that have been started but not yet completed. `saveUncrawled(exec.getCancelledTasks())` adds those. Then you have all tasks that have not completed and you can retry them.

Comment: it is clear for me. But we add these tasks only in case if **exec.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, UNIT)** as you noticed it means that all tasks terminated

Comment: Yes. This leaves the case that not all tasks could be terminated unhandled. In the [javadoc for ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (section "Usage Examples", 2nd example) it's handled.